# Assign to variable existing class

Tags: php, class, variables, variable-assignment, assign

Take this example:

```
class Container {
    public $text;
    public $variable2;
}

class Text {
    public $other_variable;
}
```

How can I assign a `Text` instance to `Container::$variable`, without using the `__construct` method?

In the end I want this effect:

```
$class = new Container();
$class->text->other_variable;
```

If I try the following, PHP gives me an error:

```
class Container {
    public $variable = new Text();
    public $variable2;
}
```

Comment: If you get an error, you should give the exact message.

Comment: Initialization is exactly what class constructors are for.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible. You have to construct a `new Text` somewhere, and this cannot be done at the time the class is defined (i.e. where you tried to do it), since class values can only be initialized with static values, not expressions. You will have to do it in the constructor.

Comment: Okey, then. If there is no other options, then Ill use __construct